# css: limit element to min(container width, container height)

Tags: css

Given the following:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">

    </div>
</div>
```

Is there a CSS way to dynamically set the `content` element's both height and width to the smaller value of the two (height or width) of the `container`?

For example if the `container` is `460x320` then `content` needs to be `320x320`.  If `container` is `240x333` then `content` should be `240x240`.
The size of the `container` are not known in advance so using fixed values won't work.
I've tried all kind of things, from `max-height/max-width` to `object-fit` but haven't been able to make it work.

Check this [jsfiddle for a demo](https://jsfiddle.net/L4aszegd/) (using javascript)

It's quite easy to do with JavaScript, but I'm looking for a CSS only trick, if it's possible.

Comment: object-fit isn't going to do anything since you're not dealing with replaced elements here.

Comment: If only `calc` had `min` and `max` subfunctions. That would be awesome.

Comment: It would also be easy if the container was the size of the window. Then you would have `vh` and `vw` and even `vmin` at your disposal, as well as media queries for the orientation. Hm, you know, I'm thinking of a hack now based on iframes.

Comment: @MrLister First of all, thanks for the `calc` suggestion, I still can't find a way to make it work in this case but I wasn't aware of that feature and it seems like a great one!  As for a hack based on iframes, that sounds like an overkill, using js will be simpler.

Comment: Use `aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;`

Answer (score 0):

- What you are asking is not possible with CSS. CSS is a **declarative language**
- So there isn't a way get size of an element, compare it's height and width and set it to another element.

Comment: I asked as there might be some tricks to make it work (even in a declarative language), for example if `max-height` and `max-length` would have behaved a bit differently then `max-height: 100%; max-width: 100%` would have done it..

Answer (score -2):

Check the snippet. This is the `CSS3 @media query` solution.

```css
.container{
  width: 240px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 333px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.70);
  border-radius: 3px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px){
  .container{
    width: 460px;
    height: 320px;
  }  
}
.content{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  top: -webkit-calc(50% - ((100% - 93px) / 2));
  top: -moz-calc(50% - ((100% - 93px) / 2));
  top: calc(50% - ((100% - 93px) / 2));
  height: -webkit-calc(100% - (333px - 240px));
  height: -moz-calc(100% - (333px - 240px));
  height: calc(100% - (333px - 240px));
  background-color: green;
}
@media (min-width: 768px){
  .content{
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: -webkit-calc(100% - (100% - 320px));
    width: -moz-calc(100% - (100% - 320px));
    width: calc(100% - (100% - 320px));
    left: -webkit-calc(50% - ((100% - (100% - 320px)) / 2));
    left: -moz-calc(50% - ((100% - (100% - 320px)) / 2));
    left: calc(50% - ((100% - (100% - 320px)) / 2));
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">I'm Absolute</div>
</div>
```

> Edit

I understand what you want. **Above snippet work only for `CSS3 @media query`**. You need to tell every time how many amount of `width` and `height` you want to give the `child` `element` using `JavaScript`. If your `child` element is `absolute` `position` then you need to set `left`, `right`, `top` and `bottom` position by `script`. You can't set `width` and `height` using Only `CSS` when randomly changing the `parent` box `height` and `width`.

Only one way you can set height and width by `CSS` you If you want to reduce some amount (i.e. `50px` of amount) all times from total `width` and total `height` when change the parent `width` and `height` randomly.

Check this snippet.

```js
const container = document.querySelector(".container");
const content = document.querySelector(".content");

const min = 300, max = 600;
function resize() {
  const width = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  const height = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;

  container.style.width = width + "px";
  container.style.height = height + "px";
}

const button = document.querySelector("button");
button.addEventListener("click", resize);

resize();
```

```css
.container{
  width: 460px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 320px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.70);
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.content{
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - ((100% - 50px) / 2));
  width: calc(100% - 50px);
  top: -webkit-calc(50% - ((100% - 50px) / 2));
  top: -moz-calc(50% - ((100% - 50px) / 2));
  top: calc(50% - ((100% - 50px) / 2));
  height: -webkit-calc(100% - 50px);
  height: -moz-calc(100% - 50px);
  height: calc(100% - 50px);
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">I'm Absolute</div>
</div>

<button>resize</button>
```

If this work then it will be good. Otherwise on way to change only by `CSS`.

Thank you.

Comment: Just posting some code will not help. At least explain what it's doing and why this snippet should solve the problem of the OP

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't doing what I need. I need `content` to always have the same `height` and `width` which will equal `min(width, height)` of the `container`. Check the difference between how it looks in the [jsfiddle of your solution](https://jsfiddle.net/pf8ezot2/) and how it looks in the jsfiddle linked in my question (click the `resize` button)

Comment: I edit the ans. Check it. If it work!!! https://jsfiddle.net/pf8ezot2/1/

Comment: If using javascript then there are simpler ways (css-wise) to make it work, but I'm looking for a css solution only, if it's possible...